# Formula for writing a specific Day of Week date value?

Tags: formula, date, button, time

Objective: create a List-View Button that writes the **date value** of the immediately upcoming Monday to a field in the selected record(s)

E.g. if Monday is Dec 5, the expected output for writing a value to that field would be: 12/5/2016

What are some recommended ways to write a "formula" so that regardless at one day in the week, a user clicking the button will achieve the expected output of writing the date of the upcoming Monday to that record?

Where I have gotten so far is this formula which is more for retrieving the text-value of a date, but I need to write a dynamically changing date value that will always be the datevalue of the upcoming Monday.

```
CASE(MOD( {!CloseDate} - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7), 0, "Saturday", 1, "Sunday", 2,"Monday", 3, "Tuesday", 4, "Wednesday", 5, "Thursday", 6,"Friday","")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google revealed [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h2muAAA):

```
CASE(
MOD(TODAY()  - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7),
0, TODAY() + 7,
1, TODAY() + 6,
2, TODAY() + 5,
3, TODAY() + 4,
4, TODAY() + 3,
5, TODAY() + 2,
6, TODAY() + 1,
DATE(9999,01,01)
)
```

that I assume could be refactored a bit and changed for your case to:

```
CloseDate + CASE(
MOD(CloseDate  - DATE(1900, 1, 8), 7),
0, 7,
1, 6,
2, 5,
3, 4,
4, 3,
5, 2,
6, 1,
0
)
```

Adding 1 to a date moves it on a day.

Comment: thank you! I was toying around with something similar after I posted this question, but this is a lot more robust. Do you know how I might package this formula into a javascript button expression? Will open it up as a separate question.

Comment: @GPP JavaScript has different building blocks so if you can't find an answer through Googling e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156434/javascript-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-from-current-date yes ask a separate question.

Comment: yep I have been googling the heck out of it, I just don't like the answers. (lol) Seems like it involves way too much code and SFDC's merge functions {!TODAY()} aren't working in here...